# How to access particular stats ("finish_reason", "elapsed_time_seconds") in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I am playing with Scrapy and I am able to scrape with it data from different URLs. One thing I am trying to obtain, and so far unsuccessfully, is stats data, particularly `finish_reason` and `elapsed_time_seconds`.

My `testspider.py`'s structure looks pretty standard:

```
class TestSpider(scrapy.Spider):

    name = 'testspider'
    def parse(self, response):
      ...
    reason = self.crawler.stats.get_value('finish_reason')
    print(reason)
    print(self.crawler.stats.get_value('elapsed_time_seconds'))
    print(self.crawler.stats.get_value('log_count/DEBUG'))
```

and on the output is the following

```
...
None # finish_reason
None # elapsed_time_seconds
75   # log_count/DEBUG
2024-02-26 16:03:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
2024-02-26 16:03:03 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
{'downloader/request_bytes': 3039,
 'downloader/request_count': 4,
 'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
 'downloader/response_bytes': 126947,
 'downloader/response_count': 4,
 'downloader/response_status_count/200': 4,
 'elapsed_time_seconds': 0.964805,
 'finish_reason': 'finished',
 'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 26, 15, 3, 3, 840387, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc),
 'httpcompression/response_bytes': 639395,
 'httpcompression/response_count': 4,
 'item_scraped_count': 68,
 'log_count/DEBUG': 75,
 'log_count/INFO': 10,
 'memusage/max': 63651840,
 'memusage/startup': 63635456,
 'request_depth_max': 2,
 'response_received_count': 4,
 'robotstxt/request_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_count': 1,
 'robotstxt/response_status_count/200': 1,
 'scheduler/dequeued': 3,
 'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued': 3,
 'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 3,
 'start_time': datetime.datetime(2024, 2, 26, 15, 3, 2, 875582, tzinfo=datetime.timezone.utc)}
2024-02-26 16:03:03 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
```

I cannot access some fields from the `def parse` method, perhaps because the script is still running? How do I achieve that? I would like to have direct access to the data in `Scrapy stats` and save it "manually" to the database (I am doing that in `pipeline.py`). How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 0):

Those two stats are only set during the engine shutdown so getting them in a callback is impossible. You can try subscribing to the `spider_closed` signal, either manually or by implementing a `closed` method in a spider, a `close_spider` method in a pipeline etc., but beware of the currently unspecified order of signal execution, as the stats you want are also set in a `spider_closed` signal handler. Alternatively you can subclass `scrapy.extensions.corestats.CoreStats` or `scrapy.statscollectors.MemoryStatsCollector` to put your code closer to the stats code.